# Content Security Policy for iframe (frame-ancestors) filled in but shows up as 'none'

Tags: nginx

Im trying to implement Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors" on nginx. I have set the header as

**add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'https://6f4f-213-3-38-224.ngrok.io';";**

But when I try to add the iframe from this site, Chrome displays the following error:

**Refused to frame 'https://sandbox.byproperti.ch/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".**

following is the server block form nginx:

```
server{
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;


        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;

        }
        location ~ /log.csv {
                deny all;
                access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
root /var/www/sandbox.byproperti.ch/doc/html;
index index.html index.html;

server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xx;
        location /doc {
                try_files $uri/ @doc;
}

location @doc {
        rewrite ^/(doc|keyword)/? /index.html?_route_=$1&$args last;
}
listen 443 ssl;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'https://6f4f-213-3-38-224.ngrok.io';";
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sandbox.byproperti.ch/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sandbox.byproperti.ch/privkey.pem;


}
```

Comment: If you visit `https://6f4f-213-3-38-224.ngrok.io` from your browser and look at the DevTools Network tab - you will see that there is no `Content-Security-Policy` header in the response from the server.

Comment: @IVOGELOV the header comes from https://sandbox.byproperti.ch/ as im putting the iframe on https://6f4f-213-3-38-224.ngrok.io which points to https://sandbox.byproperti.ch/

Comment: Connection: keep-alive
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'http://6f4f-213-3-38-224.ngrok.io';
Date: Thu, 20 Jan 2022 16:35:00 GMT
ETag: "61e96fcb-dc2"
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 Jan 2022 14:20:59 GMT
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Did you try to set HTTPS in the CSP header instead of HTTP? You can also try removing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs about frame-ancestors, see 'Single quotes surrounding the host are not allowed.'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

try without single quotes

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://6f4f-213-3-38-224.ngrok.io";
```

may be work